# ARToolKitのサンプルが動かない

Tags: visual-studio

Visual studio2017でARToolKitを使用しています。
サンプルを動かすことはできるのですが、参考書に書いてあるコードをそのまま書き写してもエラーがでて動きません。エラーの内容は下記の通りです。

> LNK2019   未解決の外部シンボル _fscanf が関数 _arLoadPatt で参照されました。  libARd.lib(arGetCode.obj)
>   LNK2019   未解決の外部シンボル _fprintf が関数 _arSavePatt で参照されました。  libARd.lib(arDetectMarker.obj)

IncludeファイルやLibファイル等の設定はできてると思います。何がいけないのかがわからず詰まっています。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ARToolKit の参考書と言いますと、[橋本直さんのこの本](http://amzn.asia/4WqAqO2)でしょうか？

Comment: はい、そちらの本のsimple.cppというやつです！

Comment: マルチポスト: https://teratail.com/questions/103902